# how to install .net framework if not already installed using autorun.inf

Tags: c#, autorun

I have a .swf file inside my CD. And I have created a program to run that .swf file, using C#. Every time user inserts that CD in drive it should run that program. But before executing that program I want to check if .NET Framework is installed or not, if its not installed it should be installed and then the .swf container should start. if .NET Framework is already installed then directly .swf player should run.

Can I do it using `autorun.inf`, if yes, how ? .. if no,what else can I use

Comment: I don't see why you need .NET and a C# application to run SWF file at all, but how is this related to Inno Setup ?

Comment: there are some external swfs which were created using ispring Quiz maker,am loading those into my swf, and there is a finish event in swfs which were created using ispring. when I dispatch that event in my swf, instead of closing only the quiz  it quits my swf too .. I dont want that.. and if I open it in a brower everything works fine.. but the client doesnt want that. it should not use the browser.. therefore I created a c# container for swf.

Comment: I tried do the task of checking and installing .net framework using inno setup. but autorun will still open the installer ..

Comment: So, you're going to execute Inno Setup installer to see if .NET is installed and if so, you run your C# client that will open that SWF and exit the installer ? And if not, the installer executes .NET's own setup ? Are you sure you need that extra Inno Setup installer step ? Do you use it for installing anything other than .NET ?

Comment: exactly .. even I want to skip the inno step .. but then what else can I use to check if .net is already installed and if not run the setup ?

Comment: It's about checking a [`few registry keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx). Using installer for this task still looks like an overkill to me. Perhaps a batch script might suffice (`reg query` the keys checking `%ERRORLEVEL%` maybe ?).

Comment: I'll try creating a batch script

Comment: solved REG HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full /v Version

:rechek
IF %errorlevel%==0 GOTO INSTALL
start QuizPlayerContainer.exe
exit
GOTO eof

:INSTALL
dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe
GOTO rechek